# How to set static client port for rmi clients?

Tags: java, rmi

I need a way to set a static port for rmi clients. The server uses a fixed port for it's connections but client side creates a dynamic port although I set a client socket factory.

The root cause I found is in the class "TCPChannel". In this class I see this code:

`TCPEndpoint.getLocalEndpoint(0, (RMIClientSocketFactory)null, (RMIServerSocketFactory)null);`

This clearly won't work as this code is unaware of my socket factory. Obviously this class is not RMI specific.

Question is - is there a way to override the tcp socket creation such that it doesn't create dynamic ports at all?

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

> client side creates a dynamic port although I set a client socket factory.

You set it how? Whatever you did, you didn't do it correctly.

But why do it at all? There are lots of disadvantages. For one thing, it will cause all RMI calls from that client to be sequentialized, possibly at two-minute intervals, or possibly cause any calls at more frequent intervals to fail with `BindExceptions`.

For another, it may have an adverse effect on DGC.

And there is no actual benefit whatsoever.

> Obviously this class is not RMI specific.

What class? And what's obvious about it?

Comment: Setting the client socket factory like this: RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(new RMIClientSocketFactoryWithSocketAdaptor(opts));

RMIClientSocketFactoryWithSocketAdaptor is my impl for socket factory.

We must have static ports as part of a security requirements that restricts any dynamic unknown ports to be open.

The class that is not RMI specific I was referring to is 'TCPChannel'.

Comment: That's about 18 years out of date. The modern way to do it is by providing an `RMIClientSocketFactory` when you *export* the object, at the *server,* which also implies it must be Serializable. `TCPChannel` is 100% RMI-specific and used for no other purpose. The security requirements you have been given are 100% pointless and should be reviewed by someone competent. Just because you can make a firewall rule about outbound ports does **NOT** mean it's a good idea. It isn't. I've been saying that here and elsewhere for nearly 20 years and I have never seen a counter-argument or counter-instance.